# iframe not loading content in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a small snippet of code that I want to load a portion of another website embedded in one of my aspx pages:

```
<tr>
   <td style="padding-left:15px;">
      <iframe src="http://www.google.com/" width="210" height="100" /></iframe>
   </td>
</tr>
```

When I view the page in IE the frame has the following warning text:

```
To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.
```

However, under no circumstances does google.com, or any other external page load for that matter.  An iframe is a pretty simple tag...is something obvious missing, or is ASP.NET imposing some contraint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the warning text - it is telling the truth. The publisher (google) does not permit hosting their site in an iframe or frame. Google does this by adding a http header, "X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY" which modern browsers will - and should - obey.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header

Comment: Okay, this makes sense.  At first I thought "publisher" referred to me and my site, hence I suspected ASP.NET settings.  Thanks a lot for clearing this up.

Answer (score 0):

No this this nothing to do with ASP.NET it is all client side issue.
I just created a plain HTML page and got same error in IE but works well in FireFox

```
   <htmL>
   Test page
   <table>
   <tr>
     <td style="padding-left:15px;">
       <iframe src="http://www.google.com/" width="210" height="100" /></iframe>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </htmL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Numerous websites actively prevent you from loading their content in a frame.  Even StackOverflow denies this.

Some actively take control of the browser and force the top level to redirect to their homepage.  There are a lot of reasons for doing this.

So, if you want to put *your own content* in an iFrame, that's fine.  However, if you want to put *other people's content* in an iFrame then I'd suggest that you stop.  It isn't considered polite behavior anymore.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  In production I'll be linking to my own web app (not built, no domain name yet) from an otherwise static project that I want to keep separate.  Ironically two sites I tested were google and SO.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to load a page from your own site in an iframe, and if you're using ASP.NET sessions, it's possible to encounter a race condition that will prevent that iframe from loading.

For third-party sites, though, as others have said, ASP.NET doesn't care; "it's a browser thing".